# How to implement 2 listViews with a scrollview when scrollView is defined "below the header to above the footer"?

Tags: android, listview, android-scrollview

layout structure is

```
<header>
<scrollView>
<footer>
```

header and footer are fixed and they should not move. but content in the scrollView needs to scroll accordingly.

ScrollView content is

```
listView1
layout - this layout has few labels
listView2
textView
```

All the ScrollView content is wrapped inside a layout as well and given as a single child to scrollView. Please provide an XMl file for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`RelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) as a parent then put your header layout and layout_below your scroll view also layout_below your footer add your alignParentTop and alignParentBottom in order to make sure they are there. I haven't tested this but it should work.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RelativeLayout>
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it is giving only 1 item of each listview

Comment: Change the inner relative layout to linear layout and use weights, will update the answer soon

Comment: tried changing it to linear layout and no luck with it as well.

Comment: try android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView with disabled Nestedscroll of both listviews